# Remove Top Margin on Body Tag

Tags: css

I have a design which needs two background images and must work in IE. So I decided to place 1 image on the html tag and the other on the body tag. So my page looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <p>Lorem...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Then a very basic css like so

```
html { background:url(../img/bg.jpg) top center no-repeat #0094d4; margin:0; padding:0; }
body { background:url(../img/bgRep.png) repeat-x; margin:0; padding:0; }
```

The only browser to render this correctly is IE7. Opera, Chrome, FF all place a ~20px margin at the top. I can remove this margin by adding some hackity css like so:

```
html { background:url(../img/bg.jpg) top center no-repeat #0094d4; position:relative; }
body { background:url(../img/bgRep.png) repeat-x; margin:0; padding:0; top:0; position:absolute; width:100%; }
```

However why does it not work to begin with, why do I need the extras? Is it a bug or a bug by design?

**EDIT**: It does appear to be a bug. When I remove the `<p>` tags then it acts correctly however with them it does not.

Comment: That's really odd.  I use `html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` all the time and it always works as expected, even with background images layered on both elements.  What happens if you use a specific DOCTYPE like XHTML Strict 1.0 (http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#docconf)?

Comment: Appears to do the same thing using <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: In your example you only show "Lorem..." as the content, but are there any nested elements in your `<body>` such as `<p>`'s or `<h1>`'s?  I've had cases where default margin/padding on nested elements shifts the `<body>` tag around.

Comment: You are correct. I had some P tags and once removed it removed the extra padding. So it is indeed a bug then.

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily a bug. It could be a case that you're running into margin collapsing (http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/margincollapsing). Essentially, two adjacent margins will collapse into whichever is "larger". "Larger" being in quotes, because it seems to be dependent on the absolute value of the margin, rather than the integer value (i.e. -26px is larger than 14px). I'm not entirely clear on this, but it is a known phenomenon, and it is part of the CSS spec.

Comment: That is whats happening, If I add a margin of 0 to <p> then the gap is removed. If I change it to something like 100 then I get a 100px gap at the top. So its a bug by design.. Worse then a bug IMO because it will probably not be fixed. Even after reading the article I don't see the point, it sounds like a crappy choice when writing the spec.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a margin for the `<p>`,  use padding instead.

And as someone mentioned above, it is caused by collapsing margins.